# Moving a picturebox out of one panel into another

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to move a picturebox from one panel, onto the windows form, then onto another panel. [image: See this image]

I can make the picturebox move by manipulating .left and .top however when it gets to the top of the panel it is on, the picturebox just disappears into the board. How can I make smoothly leave panel, go onto the main form, then enter panel 2?

Comment: Remove it from the panel first and translate its location to the form. Then slide it to where it's supposed to go.

Comment: Thanks John, didn't realize that.

@rsbarro - thank you for the help.

So the panel is at 12,467

i did this - 

`    playerPanel.Controls.Remove(cardPB)
    Me.Controls.Add(cardPB)
     cardPB.Left = startX + 12
            cardPB.Top = startY + 467`

I'm pretty new to adding/removing controls and this doesn't seem to work. I understand your solution, but implementing it is a different story.

Comment: The control's Parent property needs to change.  There isn't anything smooth about that, you will have lots and lots of trouble with the panels overlapping and clipping the picturebox.  Do avoid trying to implement a user interface that looks like Visual Studio, it is not simple and is very rarely appropriate in real programs.  The "move something from A to B" user interface is Drag+Drop.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant. I am using drag&drop to select the picturebox and I can move it instantly to the 2nd panel. I am looking to make the picturebox slide over, animated, to the other panel, rather than "teleport". Is there an "easy" way to do this?

Comment: No, it is not easy.  Get rid of the panels, replace them with Graphics.FillRectangle() in the form's Paint event handler.  Now it is easy, no need to change the Parent.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem, and I have a solution. Here's the code:

```
Panel2.Controls.Add(Picturebox) 'This "Picks Up" the Picturebox from Panel1 and drops it on Panel2
```

Also, if you have multiple picturebox's, just do this:

```
For Each pctrbox in Panel1.Controls
    Panel2.Controls.Add(pctrbox)
Next
```